# Families of Galois representations over disks

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

### Edit on Nov. 20, 2023. This question is answered below in the case that $0<r_i<1$. And indeed it is shown in the answers to not be an interesting question in that case. So please take all $r_i=1$ in what follows. I still think it is an interesting question in the case that all $r_i=1$, so I will leave it up to see if anyone has an answer in that case. The reason I was arguing against the answer below for the case $0<r_i<1$ is that for any $1>s>r>0$ the "wrong way" maps $\mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]\to \mathbb{Z}_p<\frac{x}{r}> \to \mathbb{Z}_p<\frac{x}{s}>$ are not bounded and I was thinking that meant they were not continuous, but I was mistaken: that is an implication that works for real or complex Banach spaces not here. It is just that there are many Banach norms on the ring of formal power series $\mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$ that are topologically equivalent to the product topology, yet the maps between them are only bounded in one direction. These norms are also not equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$ considered as a product in the Ind-Ban category, but again that doesn't matter for the topology. Please do not write any other comments or answers about the case that all $r_i<1$. You can read the question by replacing $R<\frac{x_1}{r_1}, \dots \frac{x_k}{r_k}>$ by $R<x_1, \dots ,x_k>$. I left the original unedited question below.

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field and let $G$ be either the Galois group of the maximal algebraic extension of $K$ in a separable algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ unramified outside a finite sent of non-archimedean places of $K$, or the Galois group of a the completion of $K$ at some place. Let $R$ be some simple non-archimedean field or ring such as $\mathbb{F}_p$,  $\mathbb{Z}_p$, or $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Is anything known about lifting continuous homomorphisms $G \to \operatorname{GL}_n(R[[x_1, \dots, x_k]])$ to continuous homomorphisms $G \to \operatorname{GL}_n(R\langle\frac{x_1}{r_1}, \dots, \frac{x_k}{r_k}\rangle)$? In other words, does there exist positive real numbers $r_1, \dots, r_k$ such that that there is a lift in general? If not, is there some criteria known for their existence? The notation $R\langle\frac{x_1}{r_1}, \dots, \frac{x_k}{r_k}\rangle$ refers to a Tate algebra.

Comment: $R[[x]]$ refers to the formal power series equipped with the product topology as a countable product of the Banach ring $R$. This notation does not refer to an open disk. By $R<\frac{x}{r}>$ I mean those formal power series $\sum a_i x^i$ such that $\lim |a_i|r^i = 0$ equipped with the norm $|\sum a_i x^i|= \sup |a_i|r^i$ and I think of this as representing functions on a closed disk of radius $r$.

Comment: The product topology on $R[[x]]$ is the same as the projective limit topology on the system $R[x]/x^n$, where the finite $R$ modules $R[x]/x^n \cong R^n$ inherit their topology from $R$. Thanks for the thought provoking answers that have been given so far.

Comment: This question is now so strewn with wreckage from previous iterations as to be incomprehensible. Please delete it, and open a new one if you still have any actual questions to ask.

Comment: This question still makes essentially no sense.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand the setup of this question: what is $R\langle x_1/r_1, \dots \rangle$ supposed to mean if $r_i$ is a real number?

That said, if $R = \mathbb{Z}_p$, then $\mathbb{Z}_p[[x_1, \dots, x_k]]$ actually embeds (continuously) into $\mathbb{Z}_p\langle x_1 / p^{a_1}, \dots, x_k / p^{a_k}\rangle$ for any strictly positive $a_1, \dots, a_k$, so you can just map your Galois represetnation along. Geometrically, this is just saying that an open polydisc of radius 1 contains a closed polydisc of any smaller radius. This is such a trivial remark that I don't think it can be the question you meant to ask; but if so, perhaps you could clarify the intended question.

Comment: I should have said that $R<\frac{x}{r}> \subset R[[x]]$ is the subring of formal power series $\sum a_i x^i$ for which $|a_i| r^i$ converges to $0$ and this subring induces a continuous group homomorphism $GL_n(R<\frac{x}{r}>) \to GL_n(R[[x]])$. This map is used to write down what lifting means in the one variable case and similarly for many variables.

Comment: I don't understand the question either. Does 'is there a lift?' mean any more or less than is image of the homomorphism contained in the subring?

Comment: Hi Simon, yes you are right. I meant to ask if the image of $G$ ever lands in that subgroup. I was thinking about the context of Mazur's article where he was sometimes able to get universal formal families of reps thought of as reps into $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p[[x_1, \dots, x_k]])$ specializing to given reps into  $GL_n(\mathbb{F_p})$. I am asking about getting  deformations beyond the formal ones.

Comment: Maybe it would have been better to ask if the image of $G$ can be conjugated to lie in the image of $GL_n(R<\frac{x_1}{r_1}, \dots, \frac{x_k}{r_k}>)$ by a single element of  $GL_n(R[[x_1, \dots, x_k]])$

Comment: Ah. I see. So you really want to study the representations up to equivalence.

Comment: The thing is that I am thinking of $\mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$ as functions on something of radius zero, a formal scheme, not an open disk.

Comment: But $\mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$ is really the ring of bounded-by-1 functions converging on the open unit disc. Any such series converges on $|x|_p<1$! So, perhaps your perception of the problem you are studying is not quite accurate.

Comment: FWIW, the notation R<X/r> already has a meaning and it isn’t that. But the notational question is unimportant. I think @tkr has very correctly diagnosed the misconception behind the question.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input. Sorry about the non-standard notation. I was thinking about lifts to $GL_n(A)$ where (in contrast to the setup in Mazur) $A$ is now a regular non-local ring, whose formal completion at some ideal is $\mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$ or $\mathbb{Q}_p[[x]]$.

Comment: This is not such a contrast to Mazur's setup as you seem to think, since $\mathbb{Z}_p[[X]]$ embeds in the ring you are calling $\mathbb{Z}_p\langle X / r\rangle$ for any $r < 1$.

Comment: I should also have said that I am using the topology on $R<\frac{x}{r}>$ generated by the norm $|\sum a_i x^i| = \sup |a_i|r^i$.

Comment: Hold on, if r < 1 then your ring Zp<X/r> is *equal* to Zp[[X]]! I think you need to rethink your question.

Comment: Yes, they are the same as rings. I will rethink my question!  I consider $\mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$ with the projective/inverse limit or adic topology and on the other hand the topology on $\mathbb{Z}_p<\frac{x}{r}>$ is described by a single norm, so I am not sure that I would consider these as equivalent objects. I have to check. Anyway, certainly $\mathbb{Q}_p[[x]]$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p<\frac{x}{r}>$ are very different and so I could have asked the same question about lifting $\mathbb{Q}_p[[x]]$ reps  (up to conjugation) to $\mathbb{Q}_p<\frac{x}{r}>$ reps.

Comment: Surely any representation into $GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p[[X]])$ can be conjugated into $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p[[X]])$?

Comment: That is because $G$ is compact, right?

Comment: I think I should have just asked about the case that all the $r_i$ are equal to $1$.

Comment: I have another question. You allow $R=\mathbb{F}_p$. What is the Tate algebra in this case? Just a polynomial ring?

Comment: Yes. $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ for $r\geq 1$ and $\mathbb{F}_p[[x]]$ for $r<1$.

Comment: I wonder if it is worth rewriting the question at this point to address all the points of clarification.

Comment: Yes, I might at some point but I have to first resolve something that seems like a contradiction. I know that these kinds of moduli problems are studied by Emerton and Gee, but I am just trying to find a way to write down simple examples of families of Galois representations, say over a Tate algebra with $r=1$.

Comment: Your maps $f_r$ and $g_r$ are never both well-defined (one is only defined if $r < 1$, the other if $r >1$, and I'm too lazy to work out which).

Comment: But you must have ignored a great deal of "too many comments" warnings to get this far.

Comment: Please, just stop commenting and start actually thinking! We've already established that (with your somewhat weird definitions) all the rings $\mathbb{Z}_p\langle \tfrac{x}{r}\rangle$ for $0 \le r < 1$ are *all actually the same ring*. So please don't waste your time and ours trying to microscopically analyse the maps in between them.